# RuntimeException when trying to use android.app.Application

Tags: android

I'm trying to use a custom class (be.myname.rssreader.util.Global) extending android.app.Application, but when I try to use its accessors, I get the following exception:

> 02-23 11:42:12.973:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2050):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
>   start activity
>   ComponentInfo{be.myname.rssreader/be.myname.rssreader.view.RSSReader}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

Before you ask, yes, it's in my manifest, as follows:

```
<application android:name=".util.Global" android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
```

The code where the exception is thrown is this:

```
global.setService(new FeedService(getApplicationContext()));
```

It's placed in the onCreate of my main Activity, immdiately after the calls to super.onCreate and setContentView.

Any ideas why this keeps throwing that exception?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check `global` isn't null ?

EDIT : 
If you're trying to access your Application class in an Activity or a Service, you have to retrieve it like that :

```
/* e.g. Global is the name of your class which extends Application */
this.global = (Global) getApplication()
```

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention that: global is in fact null, but its onCreate method is executed (I placed a Log statement in it).

According to the Android docs: "... which will cause that class to be instantiated for you when the process for your application/package is created."  (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)

So I don't get why it's null.

Comment: Ok so you're trying to access your Application class called Global from an another activity ?

Comment: Yes, I am. The documentation lead me to believe that should be possible. I'm probably just missing something. Either way, I "solved" the problem using a simple class with static fields that I set in my main onCreate().

Comment: Look at my response I edited it yesterday, did you use `getApplication()` to retrieve your application class ?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this link](http://www.anddev.org/solved_problem_with_emulator-t350.html).
Try `./emulator -wipe -data` before running your application.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm running it on my Hero, so wiping isn't a very good idea I think. But I tried executing the app on an emulator (after wiping, to be sure) and still the same exception...